# How to add a path to a database import in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, import

First of I searched all around and could not find a valid answer.

I want to import database files into a database using PHP.

The following only works if the **import.php** file resides in the same folder (**temp**) as the database files:

```
$command = "gunzip --to-stdout $backupfile | mysql -u$database_user -p$database_pass $database";
```

If I place the **import.php** in another location and add a path to the **$backupfile**, it does not work as shown below:

```
$database_path = '/home/site/public_html/temp/';
$command = "gunzip --to-stdout $database_path.$backupfile | mysql -u$database_user -p$database_pass $database";
```

What is the correct way to add the path to the database file ($backupfile) so that I can run the PHP script from any location?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$command = "gunzip --to-stdout {$database_path}{$backupfile} | mysql -u$database_user -p$database_pass $database";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with:

```
$database_path = '/home/site/public_html/temp/';
$command = 'gunzip --to-stdout ' . $database_path . $backupfile . ' | mysql -u' . $database_user . ' -p' . $database_pass . ' ' . $database;
```

or first execute command `$c2 = 'cd ' . $database_path;`